# LocalReport (WebForms) and Partial Trust, for PDF Generation

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, webforms, pdf-generation, localreport

My goal is to generate a PDF for display in a web page, either as aspx or with a generic handler. (This will link from a Silverlight page, but this is irrelevant to the problem.)

The problem is that LocalReport (Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms; Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms.dll) requires full trust, and our hosting server does not allow full trust. I am aware that ReportViewer has a remote mode that will allow it to run with partial trust, but for that I need a report server url which should probably have full trust as well, which does not solve anything.

So how do I generate PDFs from WebForms (RDLC reports) in a partially trusted environment?

**EDIT:** I am using C# 3.5 with VS 2008.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless I get any more answers to resolve the issue, this will be the best workaround:

I contacted the hosting server, and they have a separate server which allows access to Microsoft.ReportViewer (probably running full trust), but at an additional fee.

Answer (score 1):

You should check with your hosting company whatever they have a PDF creation library installed on their system first and use that.

I have not tested my self in medium trust but some people have had success in Medium Trust with this Open Source project:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/

Cheers,
Stefan

**Update**

```
private LocalReport CreateReport()
{
    LocalReport myReport = new LocalReport();
    myReport.ReportPath = "Report1.rdlc";

    // Insert parameters if needed
    ReportParameter myParam = new ReportParameter("MyParamName", "myParamValueAsString");

    myReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter[] { myParam });

    return myReport;
}
You can call the function to create the PDF:



//Create new pdf file
Byte[] mybytes = CreateReport().Render("PDF", Nothing, mimeType, encoding, extension, streamids, warnings);
```

And the mybytes can be written out with Response for download..

Comment: The problem is that LocalReport requires full access, so the server throws a security exception.

Comment: Here is a link to make iText work with partial trust: http://instantdevelopment.blogspot.com/2009/10/itextsharp-pdf-rendering-in-medium.html

Comment: Hi, I think that is only supported on Windows Server 2008 but I guess most hosting companies offers that now days.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using .NET 4 on the server, or a previous version?  I believe (based upon this help page on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.reporting.webforms.localreport.executereportinsandboxappdomain.aspx) that the ReportViewer control always executes in the sandboxed application domain.  For prior versions though (or when you are using LegacySecurityPolicy), you need to explicitly specify that the report viewer should do so by calling the ExecuteReportInSandboxAppDomain  method on the LocalReport object.  I don't know for sure, but this *may* solve your problem.

Comment: I'm using 3.5 with VS 2008. So where and when should I call this? The problem is that when I use `LocalReport` (with medium trust) in my code it does net even enter the calling method on the server, so I never get the chance to call it.

Comment: OK. A bit of further investigation it seems like many others have had this problem. Out of interest, which host are you using? Have you tried contacting them to see if they support the ReportViewer? Some forum posts indicate that if the ReportViewer DLLs are installed to the GAC the problem goes away. Have you tried not deploying the ReportViewer DLLs in your Bin folder and using the GAC version instead (if it's available)? This KB article has a hotfix for (this?) issue that may help too: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/961594. Have a read of this forum thread too: http://bit.ly/fpsLsj.

Comment: After reading StefanE's post I contacted my hosting company, and they have an alternative server environment which allows access to ReportViewer at an additional fee.

Comment: About the links, placing DLLs in the bin folder did not help me much (on my local machine), and I cannot use the hotfix (not my server).